# How to find limit that contains factorial

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I would like to know how to solve limits that contain factorial, I have only seen examples like 
$\displaystyle \frac{2^n}{n!}$

However, when I saw in the exercises that there are limits for $\displaystyle \frac{n-1}{n!}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{n!-2}{n!}$

Then I am not sure what method can I use? I try to use Squeeze Theorem, but I wasn't able to figure these out still.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your limits are $n \to \infty$.

For those examples, it might be easier to note that...

- ... in the first, $n!$ grows way faster than $n-1$, so obviously the limit would be $0$. Alternatively, apply the definition of factorial:

$$\frac{n-1}{n!} = \frac{n-1}{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots(2)(1)} = \frac{1}{n \cdot (n-2)!}$$

- ... in the second, the contribution from $2$ would be completely outweighed by that of $n!$. That is, for large $n$, intuitively, $n! - 2 \approx n!$, making the limit obviously $1$. You could also do some cancellation here, since breaking up the fraction yields
  $$\frac{n! - 2}{n!} = \frac{n!}{n!} - \frac{2}{n!} = 1 - \frac{2}{n!}$$
  which has an obvious limit.

Beyond that, I'm not sure how to help you with some factorial-based limits. Many limits you have to take as they come; there is no single rule or practice to handle them all. Personally, my favorite is Stirling's approximation,

$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \cdot \left( \frac n e \right)^n$$

which is an approximation that gets better and better for larger and larger $n$. In fact, this establishes an "asymptotic equivalence" between the two which means, often times, you can exchange these two expressions equivalently in infinite limits, which can often make things easier to see or derive.